# Trouble with ruby removing spaces from string in ERB (link_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to create a link to a url with spaces in it, my code is as follows:

```
<a href=<%= "bla bla" %>, class="ch-share-social__link">
```

This produces a link to "bla". When I remove the erb brackets and simply input it as raw text:

```
<a href="bla bla", class="ch-share-social__link">
```

Then this produces a link to "bla bla". I need to use ruby to calculate what goes inside the string so can't simply drop the ERB brackets.

Is there any way to get <%= "bla bla" %> to return 'bla bla' and not just 'bla' as it is right now?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The full block of my link is:

```
<li>
  <a href=<%= "bla bla" %>, class="ch-share-social__link">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="ch-share-social__icon" >
      <title>Share on Twitter</title>
      <use xlink:href="<%=asset_path('general.svg')%>#twitter"></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
</li>
```

If there is a better way for me to do this using link_to please let me know, I did try briefly but was getting various errors and thought this would be easier.

Comment: What about `<%= link_to 'Bla', 'bla bla', class: 'ch-share-social__link' %>`?

Comment: I tried but I'm not sure how to structure a link_to block with all my nested code - I've edited the question to include it I probably should have done that from the start

Comment: <%= link_to ... do %>...<% end %> may work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to 'bla bla', class: 'ch-share-social__link' do %>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="ch-share-social__icon" >
      <title>Share on Twitter</title>
      <use xlink:href="<%=asset_path('general.svg')%>#twitter"></use>
    </svg>
  <% end %>
</li>
```